# Does Bootstrap not have a Official Sidebar Menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does Bootstrap not have a sidebar menu? Anytime I try to research this, I get redirected to website below. Just curious if getbootstrap Official has a sidebar menu.

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/ a Blackrock digital website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bootstrap 4 there isn't something like a sideNav already built as a component but , with little effort on css and the tools that bootstrap give to you, it isn't a big deal to make it.

```
//simple css class for the sidenavBox
.sideNavBox {
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #545555;
}
```

Comment: what you mean with "how would I call it like this?"

Comment: <div class ="sideNavBox"> <ul><li>one link</li><li>another link</li></ul> </div> it is right to create the box in the html

Comment: thanks, gave points and accepted answer, feel free to thumbs up question also